# How to check the voLTE capability in Android device?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I want to find whether the phone have voLTE capability or not. I found `isVolteAvailable()` function in [`TelephonyManager.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#L4751)

That function is annotated with `@hide` and Even if it available, The telephony manager will give me data only whether it is enabled or not. Is there any way to find out whether the android device supports voLTE.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can find that information executing this code on adb shell.

```
adb shell
settings list global preferred_network_mode
```

After executing the command above, a list appears on shell, and you can find the field `volte_vt_enabled=1`. that shows if your mobile suppports VoLTE.